# Отучить KDE автозапускать последние приложения

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde

Задача такая: отучить KDE автостартовать приложения, которые были запущены в предыдущей сессии. Сами приложения не прописаны в автозапуске, KDE их запускает сам. Искал по всем настройкам, в гугле, ответа не нашел. Как отучить KDE автозапускать последние приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, эта настройка запрятана в "Управлении сеансами", что в разделе "Запуск и завершение". Мне и в голову не могло придти искать эту функцию там, так как я считал, что сеансы связаны исключительно с входом нескольких пользователей в систему. Итого,что бы отключить эту фитчу идем в "Параметры системы" -> "Запуск и завершение" -> "Управление сеансами" и ставим "Начинать с пустого сеанса".